# how to reset the view position to origin after scale

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios6

There's two views in my app, viewA(green) and subviewB(red). The initial state of my app is as following:
[image]

I use the following code to change the transform of viewA:

```
CGFloat scale = 0.4;
self.viewA.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(scale, scale, 1);
```

as a result, the subviewB is scaled and translated

[image]

but there's a problem for my app: I need the subViewB is still at the top-left corner in viewA, but subviewB is look at moved to center of viewA, it's weird that the origin point of subviewB is still (0,0), what can I do to move the subviewB to top-left corner?

Comment: Do you have to use CATransform3DMakeScale? If not, then try this: `self.viewA.transition = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);`

Comment: you mean self.viewA.transform? I have to scale subviews of viewA, but should not scale viewA. Even though I can scale viewA, the position of viewA is still changed after scale using CGAffineTransformMakeScale

Comment: tried to find solution but couldn't animation run.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try the code given,

```
subviewB.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(test.transform, scale, scale);
```

It will work :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with scaling and auto layout but in a uiscrollview.  I used CATransform3DMakeScale in the end to fix all my issues.

https://github.com/hansdesmedt/AutoLayout-scrollview-scale

This is an example of an UIScrollView with custom paging completely made in AutoLayout and is scalable (CATransform3DMakeScale) with long press and tap to zoom. iOS 6 and 7 compatible.