# On iOS 7, setting a layer transform in viewDidLoad breaks auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout

On iOS 7, applying a transform to a view's layer in `viewDidLoad` appears to break Auto Layout.

In a new project I created two views, one red and one green, and gave them identical constraints (center horizontally in superview, distance from top layout guide, width, and height). The app normally looks like this (the red view is completely covered):

[image]

Then I made `ViewController.swift` look like this:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var subview: UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        subview!.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.6, 0.6, 1)

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.subview!.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        }
    }
}
```

While the transform is applied the app looks like this (note that the origin of the transform is wrong):

[image]

After the transform has been removed the app looks like this (note that the green view is in the wrong place):

[image]

The wrong positioning seems to last the lifetime of the view. Am I doing something wrong or is this a straight bug? Has anyone else run into it and found a clean workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
subview!.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6, 0.6)
```

in place of

```
subview!.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.6, 0.6, 1)
```

I had a similar issue and that helped. Inspiration for answer:
[how to reset the view position to origin after scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436937/how-to-reset-the-view-position-to-origin-after-scale)